# In Project how can I avoid that when the end date of a task changes the duration is re-calculated?

Tags: ms-project

I am finding the following problem with Microsoft Project.

I defined a task that for example have a duration of 10 days but these 10 days can be spread in a longer time (for example one month) because the involved resources in the meantime are working on other tasks.

My problem is that when I change the end date, Project automatically re-calculate the duration and so I have a bigger number of what I expect. How can I avoid that Project automatically calculate the duration of a task when the end date changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really have is a task with 10 days work that may be spread over 10 or more days duration. In other words the work content is 80 hours, assuming a normal 8 hour workday, but the duration is variable.

I suggest you make the task a Fixed Work type task. Then assign the resource and enter the work content in the Work field. Project will automatically set the duration at 10 days, given a default resource assignment of 100%. Now, if the resource isn't available full time for this task, do NOT enter a new finish date as this will set a constraint, rather, enter a new value for the estimated duration. The work content will remain at 80 hours but Project will automatically adjust the resource assignment to represent the new plan.

Note, Project will always spread the resource work linearly over the duration of the task. If you want to adjust the days & hours the resource will work, do so manually via the Task or Resource Usage views.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding this topic, let’s talk based on many years of cross-border e-commerce experience!
First of all, when we choose a platform or invest in something, we must have the ability and determination to think independently and do something.
About aibapa, based on comprehensive information research, it is a website developed in the UK based on the investment background of Tesco, the largest offline retailer in the UK. Although it is an emerging cross-border e-commerce platform, it has been operating for 9 years. , various infrastructures have been improved.
Comprehensive analysis aibape is a platform worth considering. It has the following characteristics:
Broad market prospects: aibape serves 15 countries in Europe and South America, with a population of 510 million, and e-commerce penetration is low, which means there is a lot of room for growth. According to the development trend and promotion plan of aibape, it will be a good opportunity to recruit cross-border sellers in Asia.
Strong e-commerce growth: Despite the impact of the global political and economic crisis, e-commerce sales in Europe and South America can still maintain an annual growth rate of 19%.